# How to move Android Studio's menu bar

Tags: android

Sorry, I know this is a stupid question, but I don't know what I should to do. I already searching for solution over the internet no found nothing on it.

This is what my Android Studio looks like, I don't know what I did before:

[image: my android studio]

I want my Android Studio to look like this:

[image: my friend AS]

Please help me.

Answer (score 38):

Go to **View** menu and *enable* **Toolbar**

[image: Enable Android studio's toolbar]

Comment: In AS 4.0 it is `View` > `Appearance` > `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 21):

Edit:
You get your friends layout by clicking on "View" and then check "Toolbar".
What i wrote below this paragraph is all nonsense, but I leave it there anyway, maybe it is still of help.

I believe your friend has the default view. You can try resetting your view by going to "Window" and "Restore Default Layout". If that does not work try "File" and "Settings", and in there "Appearance and Behavior" and "Menus and Toolbars", and in the bottom right you can select "Restore Default".

But careful, it might reset something that you changed somewhere else as well, so be sure it won't be a problem for you.

Answer (score 13):

Go to View > Disable all Toolbars,Status Bars,etc.

Again, go to View > Enable Toolbar,Tool Buttons and Status Bar!

Back to Original...Enjoy!