# How do I add an icon to the Android Studio action toolbar?

Tags: android, android-studio

## Context

In Android Studio, a developer can select actions icons such as these in the toolbar:
[image]

There are also other actions inside various drop down menus, for example, the Version Control System menu:
[image]

## Issue

There are certain actions that I use frequently, i.e. the [image] function.  Since I use it so much, I would rather not have to go through the drop down menus every time to reach it.

Is there a way to add functions like these to the action toolbar of Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click toolbar, you will see below:
[image]

Select an item of Main Toolbar and click **add after...**

[image]

Comment: When I click add after, I add the push icon after the commit icon uner the VCS operations of the main toolbar.  I apply these changes and press ok, but the main toolbar remains the same.

Comment: Never mind, I had to split my toolbar from  directories as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45657573/how-to-move-android-studios-menu-bar).

Comment: @BenjaminSarkis  Try add it after "Open..."